# I have problems with constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, constructor

Hi I wanted to add text from variable to div when button is pressed. But I got stuck. Text is added at the bottom or not at all.

```js
    var text=['text1','text2','text3'];
    var title=['title1','title2','title3'];
    var i=0;
    $("#Construct").on("click",function()
        {
            newTitle = document.createElement("div");
            newTitle.innerHTML = title[i];
            newTitle.classList.add("title")
            newText = document.createElement("div");
            newText.innerHTML = text[i];
            newText.classList.add("text")
    
            insertplace = document.getElementById("#insert");
    
            document.body.insertBefore(newText, insertplace.nextSibling);
            document.body.insertBefore(newTitle, insertplace.nextSibling);
            
            i++;
      
        });
```

```css
#example{
   background: lightblue;
   width: 400px;
}
.text { 
    color: black; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    text-align: left; 
}
.title { 
    color: black; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 28px; 
    text-align: right;
}
#created{
      background: green;
      width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="Construct" class="button" type="button" value="Construct" >
    <div id="example">
      <div class="title">
      Title
      </div>
      <div class="text">
      Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="created">
        <div id="insert"> </div>
    </div>
```

Also can I create programmed buttons this way? I would like to have them play sound file while having path to the file in string variable.

Comment: Any reason you're not using React or Angular? Things like this are much easier to do in those modern frameworks.

Comment: @JohnBrandli Are you serious? Adding libraries and frameworks for something so trivial?

Comment: On a content note, don't use `.innerHTML` when you're just setting text. use `.textContent`. But if you're already using jQuery, why are you using document.createElement? Just use `let x = $('div').text(...).addClass(...),appendTo(...)` because that's way easier.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you're already using jQuery...

Comment: And on a "your code is fine, but you have a typo" note: you're using `document.getElementById("#insert");` which obviously won't work. Either use `document.querySelector("#insert");`, with the `#` in the selector, or use `document.getElementById("insert")` without the `#`.

Comment: @JohnBrandli, I think you mistake ScottMarcus with the OP...

Comment: not intending to `pile on` but I think your nomenclature should be corrected, there is no `constructor` in the code you posted and nothing that behaves as one. @magister

Comment: @JohnBrandli exactly!  OP is already using jQuery (for one line).  He should be advised to consider using less not more frameworks for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getElementById()` implies that you'll pass an `id`, so you don't add "#".

Also, instead of `.insertBefore()`, use `.appendChild()` on the insert area.

With those things corrected, you'll still run into an issue when you click the button for the 4th time because your array only has 3 items, so a check on the variable before incrementing it is needed.

```js
let insertPlace = document.getElementById("insert");

var text=['text1','text2','text3'];
var title=['title1','title2','title3'];
var i=-1;  // Start before the first index

$("#Construct").on("click",function(){
   // Check to see if there is another item in the array
   if(i < text.length -1) {
     i++;
   } else {
     console.log("There are no more items to create elements from.");
     return; // exit the function
   }

   newTitle = document.createElement("div");
   newTitle.innerHTML = title[i];
   newTitle.classList.add("title")
   newText = document.createElement("div");
   newText.innerHTML = text[i];
   newText.classList.add("text")
    
   // With .getElementById(), you don't add "#"
   insertplace = document.getElementById("insert");
    
   insertPlace.appendChild(newText);
   insertPlace.appendChild(newTitle);
    

   
});
```

```css
#example{
   background: lightblue;
   width: 400px;
}
.text { 
    color: black; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    text-align: left; 
}
.title { 
    color: black; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 28px; 
    text-align: right;
}
#created{
      background: green;
      width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="Construct" class="button" type="button" value="Construct" >
    <div id="example">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="created">
        <div id="insert"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note that jQuery's already being used, so those create-and-set instructions can be trivially one-linered as well, no need to keep that mixed jquery/vanilla JS

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know, but this user is obviously new so I want to keep the solution as close to their original as possible. Optimization can wait.

Comment: there's optimization, and there's bad code. using vanilla JS to build DOM nodes with insertbefore(node.nextsibling) hackery is plain bad. Teaching them clean jQuery in the process is infinitely better for them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans IMHO (and as a professional IT trainer for 25 years), I would say that is exactly the wrong advice. The DOM has matured and JQuery is overused for things that you should NOT use a library for at all. Doing DOM work with the DOM API is not "plain bad", it's in fact, the best approach. Using libraries and frameworks unnecessarily is plain bad.

Comment: Also, no one should use any library or framework until they understand vanilla JavaScript and the standard client APIs. Jumping into JQuery before knowing JavaScript and the DOM API is always 100% a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ScottMarcus for exactly that reason I was considering posting a vanilla solution.  I am a little surprised you did not, since jQuery is only used for the one event.  likely doesnt matter, I assume he is using it elsewhere in his project anyway.

Comment: @NappingRabbit As I stated a few comments back, I wanted to answer the question without changing too much of what the OP is already doing because it's obvious that the OP is new. JQuery really isn't relevant to this question or the answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus no, I read it and I got it, it just seems like a missed opportunity.  OP is obviously just getting started, maybe he doesn't know he does not need jQ for this task.  I doubt it, but maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You have a simple typo in your code (`getElementById` takes an id, not a queryselector for an id, so don't put `#` in there). But the real issue here is that you're mixing jQuery and vanilla JS. If you're already using jQuery, *keep using jQuery* and take advantage of how it lets you very easily build, update, and insert DOM nodes:

```
const title=['title1','title2','title3'];
const text=['text1','text2','text3'];
const insertPlace = $("#insert");

$("#Construct").on("click",function() {
  if (text.length) {
    $("<div>").text(text.shift()).addClass("text").insertAfter(insertPlace);
    $("<div>").text(title.shift()).addClass("title").insertAfter(insertPlace);
  }    
});
```

Comment: this just changes text into 3

Comment: into 3... what? Every time you click, the first text/title get unshifted (it's like `array.pop()` but from the start, instead of the end). Those are inserted after your insertion point. The next time you click, the same thing happens, so you get the next pair. Then Once more, you get the last one. Then you've exhausted your data and there is nothing left to append.

Comment: I did it and I get 3 after clicking https://jsfiddle.net/magister5/7wm1d5zj/2/

Comment: ahh, yeah that's silly, updated the answer to do the right thing instead (unshift is the head equivalent of push, not pop...)